# attempt to index a nil value (global 'GLOBAL')

Tags: lua

So I am currently working on a mod for a steam game called "Don't Starve Together" and everything was working fine but suddenly I ran into an issue where it says that I am attempting to index a nil value. I am fairly new to lua so any help is appreciated.

full code:  https://srcb.in/6pKb8vCMr5

error: https://ibb.co/F4Y4yJp

Comment: In the line `local require = GLOBAL.require`, what do you think `GLOBAL` is? Did you mean `_G`?

Comment: Also, you should add your code and error to this post as text, rather than as off-site links and images.

Answer (score 1):

You index a variable named `GLOBAL` in the first line of your script.

```
local require = GLOBAL.require
```

According to Lua `GLOBAL` is a global nil value. That means that there is neither a local variable nor a global variable with that name. Hence you are not allowed to index it because this wouldn't make any sense.

So find out why you want to index `GLOBAL`. Either ensure it is not nil or do not index it.

#### Edit:

a quick websearch suggests that you're supposed to run your code in some sandboxed environment where `GLOBAL` provides access to some of Lua's standard functions. So it appears that you're environment is not set up properly. Refer to the games API manual to find out what to do.

If you want to use Lua's standard `require` simply use

```
local require = require
```

Although making require local would only make sense if you will call it very frequently which is usually not the case.